# django update model doesn't affect auto_now timestamp

Tags: django-models

I've been trying to debug why the last_updated field in several of my models wasn't being updated when doing eg `model.objects.filter(**lookups).update(**defaults)` with eg:

```py
class PaymentMethod(models.Model):
    MONTHLY_DIRECT_DEBIT = 'MDD'
    QUARTERLY_DIRECT_DEBIT = 'QDD'
    CASH_OR_CHEQUE = 'CAC'
    PAY_IN_ADVANCE = 'PYM'
    PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
        (MONTHLY_DIRECT_DEBIT, 'Monthly Direct Debit'),
        (QUARTERLY_DIRECT_DEBIT, 'Quarterly Direct Debit'),
        (CASH_OR_CHEQUE, 'Cash or Cheque'),
        (PAY_IN_ADVANCE, 'Pay Monthly in Advance'),
        
    )
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
```

Here I am just trying to update a single entry and don't need to load the instance into memory. This seems to be a won't fix 'bug' explained in docshttps://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15566 (for some reason I can't see it in the docs).

However, what is the best way to update a single row including the last_updated field (without needing to load into memory)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't work as posted in this issue (declared as won't fix) https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22981

.update() will only update the fields explicitly passed to it, so datetimefields with auto_now =True aren't updated.

Answer (score 4):

I know the documented behavior is that `.update()` will ignore updating `auto_now[_add]` fields as is also confirmed by Yunti's answer. However, for those who wish to force the desired effect - for example, having an `auto_now` field updated as part of an `.update()` invocation, the following approach seems to work...

```
update(field1=val1, field2=val2,..., last_update=datetime.now())
```

Where `last_update` is a `models.DateTime` type field with (or without) `auto_now=True`. However, note that if you pass some other value to this field other than `now()` - the current timestamp that is, the ORM doesn't help in correcting this to the current timestamp (which is what the `auto_now` flag semantics imply). So, for example, in the following snippet, the `last_update` field does get overridden with the specified timestamp, irrespective of whether it's past, present or future...

```
    update(field1=val1, field2=val2,..., last_update=datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'))
```

So, if you wish to enforce the standard semantics of `auto_now` when making your calls to `update()`, ensure to *correctly* pass the current timestamp as the update value to these fields. You are doing it manually (due to a flaw/deficiency in the Django ORM implementation), but you are doing it correctly thus.

Comment: Just use `now()` from `django.utils.timezone` and it'll do it with appropriate TZ info.

Comment: You may want to consider using the `django.db.models.functions.Now()` database function rather than `django.utils.timezone.now()`. That way, the `update` statement will use the time provided by the database, rather than the time provided by your client (the two are not necessarily synchronized).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.save(update_fields=['...'])` method to update the Django model field value.

This approach is best at this current age and time.

syntax: `model_object.save(update_fields['fieldname', 'fieldname', '....'])`

Steps to this approach:

1. Get the object (row) of the model using the `objects.get()` method.
2. Store the value in the model fields.
3. Include the model fields along with the "auto_now" DateTime field in .save(update_fields=['...']). Like this: `.save(update_fields=['field_name_one', 'field_name_two', 'auto_now_date_time_field'])`.
4. Finally invoke the .save(update_fields=['...']).

Your data will be stored including the DateTime field with auto_now=True.

**!NOTE:** *DateTime field with **auto_now=True** stores the **time that is set on the machine where the database is running***

Please check the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) for more details on this method.

**models.py**

```python
class Blog(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    blog_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    blog_body_text = models.TextField()
    last_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_name
```

Update the model's object in **views.py**

```python
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import blog

def Update_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        

        updated_username = request.POST['username']
        blog_name = request.POST['blog_name']
        updated_blog_body_text = request.POST['blog_body_text']

        # models object using .get()
        blog_object = blog.objects.get(blog_name=blog_name)

        blog_object.username = updated_username
        blog_object.blog_body_text = updated_blog_body_text

        # .save(update_fields=['...']) method
        blog_object.save(update_fields=['username', 'blog_body_text', 'last_updated_at'])

        return HttpResponse("updated successfully", status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("failed to update (not a 'POST' request)", status=400)
```